# Automatically maximize browser window using Javascript without pressing any key

Tags: javascript, html

I want to maximize the browser window when online exam starts. After completing the exam the browser automatically go back to its previous state. Is it possible using Javascript?

Comment: Do you mean full-screen instead of maximize? That is possible. But the browsers will not allow you to hijack users and prevent them from exiting it.

Comment: i want fullscreen so that the browser doesn't show the taskbar menu or tab menu

Comment: See the linked question (answer with the most up votes, not the accepted answer). But like I said, it's impossible to prevent the user from exiting it.

Answer (score -2):

```
let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser(browser).build();
await driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: let browser = "chrome";